# \footnote only show number but with no contents at the bottom

Tags: beamer, footnotes

I'm just trying to show the reference by using the \footnote. However, the beamer only show the number of footnote but with no contents at the bottom. Here is my codes

```
\frame{
    \frametitle{Motivation}
    %\begin{figure}
%        \centering
%        \includegraphics[width=2.5in]{figs/MTC.eps}
%        %\caption{}\label{}
%    \end{figure}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item [\small$\square$] Internet of Things (IoT) networks
      \begin{itemize}
         \item [$\blacktriangleright$] Massive access: the number of devices $k$ may be comparable to the coding blocklength $n$ \footnote{X. Chen, T.-Y. Chen, and D. Guo, ``Capacity of Gaussian many-access channels,'' \emph{IEEE Trans. Inform. Theory}, vol. 63, no. 6, pp. 3516-3539, Jun. 2017.},
         \begin{itemize}
           \item  Conventional MAC: $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mathrm{Capacity}(k,n)$
           \item  Massive access channels: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mathrm{Capacity}(k_{n})$
         \end{itemize}
         \item [$\blacktriangleright$] Massive capacity: fiber-like user experience. Multiple antennas system
should be considered in the future wireless network.
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
}
```

and the silde by this code [image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please, extend your code fragment to complete small document, which we can compile as it is.

Answer (score 1):

with the complete file included, the citation appears in the footnote as expected on my box (Linux, TeXLive 2018, lualatex):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame{
    \frametitle{Motivation}
    %\begin{figure}
%        \centering
%        \includegraphics[width=2.5in]{figs/MTC.eps}
%        %\caption{}\label{}
%    \end{figure}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item [\small$\square$] Internet of Things (IoT) networks
      \begin{itemize}
         \item [$\blacktriangleright$] Massive access: the number of devices $k$ may be comparable to the coding blocklength $n$ \footnote{X. Chen, T.-Y. Chen, and D. Guo, ``Capacity of Gaussian many-access channels,'' \emph{IEEE Trans. Inform. Theory}, vol. 63, no. 6, pp. 3516-3539, Jun. 2017.},
         \begin{itemize}
           \item  Conventional MAC: $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mathrm{Capacity}(k,n)$
           \item  Massive access channels: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mathrm{Capacity}(k_{n})$
         \end{itemize}
         \item [$\blacktriangleright$] Massive capacity: fiber-like user experience. Multiple antennas system
should be considered in the future wireless network.
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

Kind regards,

Ernst

[image: output of code above with lualatex 1.07.0]

Comment: Thanks, I have figured out what happens on my tex file.

Answer (score 0):

after completing your code snippet to complete small document your footnote appears on bottom of the frame (compile with MikTeX and use last version of the `beamer` package):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%----
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\small$\square$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[circle]
%
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\scriptsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Motivation}
    \begin{itemize}
\item Internet of Things (IoT) networks
        \begin{itemize}
    \item  Massive access: the number of devices $k$ may be comparable to the coding blocklength $n$
            \footnote{X. Chen, T.-Y. Chen, and D. Guo, ``Capacity of Gaussian many-access channels,'' \emph{IEEE Trans. Inform. Theory}, vol. 63, no. 6, pp. 3516-3539, Jun. 2017.},
            \begin{itemize}
       \item  Conventional MAC: $\lim_{k\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathrm{Capacity}(k,n)$
       \item  Massive access channels: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathrm{Capacity}(k_{n})$
            \end{itemize}
    \item  Massive capacity: fiber-like user experience. Multiple antennas system should be considered in the future wireless network.
        \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

off-topic: observe difference how list are used and definitions of `beamertemplate`s in preamble. on this way their your in all your presentation will be more consistent.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!